# How do I get an extended control panel for users other than root in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I log into phpmyadmin as the root DB user, I get a long control panel at the top of the page:

[image: Control panel for root user]

I am particularly interested in the designer feature. If I log on as another user, even one that has the **same** privileges as root, I see this in the same location:

[image: No features for other users]

How do I allow users other than root to have access to these extra features, particularly the designer feature?

Comment: You need to configure the "phpMyAdmin configuration storage", which is explained in phpMyAdmin's documentation. Or maybe this other user is part of a group which has a limited menu configured.

Comment: Ah. User groups have menu configurations?

Comment: Yes. From the doc, "Since release 4.1.0 you can create different user groups with menu items attached to them. Users can be assigned to these groups and the logged in user would only see menu items configured to the usergroup he is assigned to. To do this it needs two tables “usergroups” (storing allowed menu items for each user group) and “users” (storing users and their assignments to user groups)."

Comment: Interesting. Removing the user group seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user belonging to a user group where some menus have been disabled can produce this effect.